# Spring and character encoding in properties files

Tags: spring, character-encoding, thymeleaf

I know, that there were many questions about the encoding in properties files, but I couldn't find answer which would help me, so I'm asking one more time.

So I have a Spring 4 based project with Java Config and with Thymeleaf as the templating engine.
I want to specify some labels in properties file, and read values of properties in the .html files using Thymeleaf's directive #{property.name}.

I already set up enconding in Character encoding Filter, I also set up encoding in messageSource (I'm using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource). I also added property to pom.xml:
        UTF-8

And honestly, I'm out of ideas what I could do wrong.
What I didn't do from things which I have found in stackoverflow answers:

I didn't configured ant/maven native2ascii plugin, as I tried to change my characters (like ó or ł) to ascii counterparts, and almost all characters was still replaced by '??' signs.

I have also didn't configured maven-resource-plugin as I'm not sure why should I use it if all .properties files are available ?

**EDIT**

MessageSource definition:

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resource.setBasenames("/i18n/messages");
    resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resource;
}
```

WebApp initialization:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
            new CharacterEncodingFilter());
    fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
}
```

Maven properties definition
    
        UTF-8
        (other properties)

Reference in HTML file (in anchor tag):

```
th:href="@{about.html}" th:text="#{navigation.about}"
```

Properties files are: webapp/i18n/message_en_EN.properties, webapp/i18n/message_pl_PL.properties (both are saved in UTF-8 encoding by Intellij)

Comment: if you have code that you have attempted to get working, please add it in as it will help drastically improve troubleshooting

Comment: Code provided. That's all what I have done to get the encoding working, but it still doesn't work as it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the problem was lying in Thymeleaf.

I was using ServletContextTemplateResolver and ThymeleafViewResolvere, and I had to set encoding in those two objects:

```
@Bean(name="templateResolver")
public ServletContextTemplateResolver getServletContextTemplateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/somepath/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean(name="viewResolver")
public ThymeleafViewResolver getThymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(getTemplateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return viewResolver;
}
```